# Getting started with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, express, npm, mongoose

When I put in the code

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
```

I get back the following error:

```
 /Users/user/shares3/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:1069
        catch {
              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/shares3/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/add_user.js:6:17)
```

This code is as simple as could be. I have tried reinstalling the mongoose package.

Do you have any ideas on how I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: Make sure you're using a recent version of Node.js

Comment: @Brett, which version of Node.js were you running when that happen?

Comment: @Normal I was using node version 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by using a (very) old version of Node.js that doesn't support `try/catch`.